# ValueError: Invalid broadcasting comparison with block values - how to resolve it in pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, array-broadcasting

Hi I have two data frames and trying to compare the values in it but facing a ValueError in broadcasting:

```
    dict_1 = {'a': {0: [{'value': 'A123',
    'label': 'Professional'},
   {'value': 'B141', 'label': 'Passion'}]},
 'b': {0: [{'value': 'B5529',
    'label': 'Innovation'},
   {'value': 'B3134', 'label': 'Businees Value'},
   {'value': 'B3856',
    'label': 'Electrofication'},
   {'value': 'B3859', 'label': 'Insurance'},
   {'value': 'B3856', 'label': 'Requirements'},
   {'value': 'B3345', 'label': 'Stories'}]},
    "c" : "hello"}
    
    dict_2 = {'a': {0: np.nan},
 'b': {0: [{'value': 'B4785',
    'label': 'Innovation'},
   {'value': 'B4635', 'label': 'Businees Value'},
   {'value': 'B1234', 'label': 'Requirements'},
   {'value': 'B9853', 'label': 'Stories'}]},
          'c': "hello"
         }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)
```

Here I wanted to compare two rows only but not two complete dataframes (as I had a scenario that `shape of df1=(500, 2)` and shape of `shape of df2 = (1, 2)`). So I used the below code two extract the different values in the rows .

```
df1[~(df1[['a', 'b', 'c']] == df2[['a', 'b', 'c']].iloc[0])]
```

The desired result should be:

[image]

Here, `df2` which has one row should compare with every row values of `df1`(in my scenario I have more than 1 row). If they are identical then it should be `nan` else I should get the corresponding values of df1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask` and replace `True` matches with `np.nan`. If `df2` and `df1` have a single row

```
condition = df1 == df2

df1.mask(condition, other=np.nan)
```

Output:

[image]

Now if `df2` has more than one row you can apply a callable that return `True` or `False` values, in this case calling `apply` to compare each row of `df1` to the first element of `df2`. Otherwise one gets a different shape error.

```
dict_1 = {'a': 
              {0: [{'value': 'A123',
                   'label': 'Professional'},
                   {'value': 'B141', 'label': 'Passion'}],
               1: [{'value': 'B123',
                   'label': 'Professional'},
                   {'value': 'B141', 'label': 'Passion'}]
              },
 
          'b': {0: [{'value': 'B5529',
                'label': 'Innovation'},
                {'value': 'B3134', 'label': 'Businees Value'},
                {'value': 'B3856',
                'label': 'Electrofication'},
                {'value': 'B3859', 'label': 'Insurance'},
                {'value': 'B3856', 'label': 'Requirements'},
                {'value': 'B3345', 'label': 'Stories'}],
                
                1: [{'value': 'C5529',
                'label': 'Innovation'},
                {'value': 'B3134', 'label': 'Businees Value'},
                {'value': 'B3856',
                'label': 'Electrofication'},
                {'value': 'B3859', 'label': 'Insurance'},
                {'value': 'B3856', 'label': 'Requirements'},
                {'value': 'B3345', 'label': 'Stories'}],
               },
    
          "c" : {0: "hello", 1: "hola"}}

# New df1 with two rows
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)

condition = df1.apply(lambda x: x==df2.iloc[0], axis=1)

df1.mask(condition, other=np.nan)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It works for this problem. But in my scenario i have different columns too in both dataframes. For example df1 has columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]  and df2 has columns = ["a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]. So here corresponding columns should be only compared  and then I wanted apply  df1.mask(cond, other=np.nan)

Comment: @Vas , both `df1` and `df2` share the columns `["a", "b", "c"]`, so in the filter condition `condition` subsetting `df1` and `df2` on `["a", "b", "c"]` should work.